Change the permission in Azure devops Library
Accidentally, I changed the permission to 'Reader' from 'Administrator.' As a result, I am unable to modify or delete the variable group. Is there any other way to resolve this issue?
unfortunately, we have disabled the inheritance option for the variable group.

Looking the solution for the issue

As per the users of the library, you need to ask Project collection administrator to help remove the Variable group, or add you back as administrator of the variable group, then it can be removed.

According to the Library security, Creators and Administrators should have the permissions to either edit or delete the variable group.
Administrators can also manage membership of all other roles for the item.
The user who created an item gets automatically added to the Administrator role for that item. By default, the following groups get added to the Administrator role of the library:

Build Administrators
Release Administrators
Project Administrators


unfortunately, we disabled the inheritance option for the variable group.

@Tamilselvan administators should still be able to fix it, right? Otherwise contact MS Support
